# why might this demonstration regarding subgroups not be simple and obvious?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

If $H$ is a subgroup from $G$ so why:

$$a,b\in H\implies ab^{-1}\in H.$$

I thought that if $b\in H$ so $b^{-1} \in H$ since $H$ is a group as well, as $H$ is a subgroup so that's closed under the operator $(\cdot)$ from $G$ ($ab=a\cdot b$) so $ab \in H$ but because $b^{-1} \in H$ so $ab^{-1}\in H$.

But my professor put another demonstration out harder than this which I can't even understand. He used the fact that the null element and inverse for both $G$ and $H$ are the same.

Is my demonstration wrong?

Comment: I think my professor is angry to me, xD.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that it depends on what your definition of a subgroup is. Assuming that the definition is just a group using the same binary operation, then you would first have to show that the inverse in both groups are the same. This is probably what your professor was getting at.

Comment: Just to explain further, if we replace groups with monoids then it is no longer true that the identity of a submonoid is the same, so we would have to be more careful using a proof like the one you gave.

Comment: @Fishbane: The definition of submonoid requires that the identity of the submonoid coincide with the identity of the monoid (and morphisms are required to carry identities to identities, which is not a consequence of respecting the operation as it is for groups). That is, "monoid" is not shorthand for "semigroup that has an element that acts as the identity", so submonoid does not just mean "subsemigroup that has an identity".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, this is true under the standard definition of a submonoid, however my point was to illustrate that is structures similar to groups things can behave unexpectedly and explain why it is important to check that things behave how we want them to. I admit perhaps I could have used more precise language but I felt it would have just added confusion.

Comment: The important point is: what is your *precise* definition of "group" and "subgroup", and what have you proven about subgroups up to now? Different definitions and sequence of proofs lead to different arguments being valid (or some arguments being circular) so without full context, it is impossible to say if your proof is valid in your context or if it assumes things you have not yet proven.

Answer (score 1):

Your prof is establishing some basic results which you are using  in your proof: That the identity of $H$ is the identity of $G,$ and that if $b\in H$ then the inverse of  $b$ in the group $H$ is equal to the inverse of $b$ in the group $G.$

Let $1_G$ be the identity of $G$. Let $1_H$ be the identity of $H$.

(1a). For any $x,x'\in G$ we have $xx'=x$ iff $x'=1_G$...(1b).  In the case $x=x'=1_H$, since $1_H$ is the identity of $H$ and since $x,x'\in H$, we have $xx'=x1_H=x$ , so we conclude by (1a) that $1_G=x'=1_H$.

(2a). For any $b\in G$ there is a unique $z\in G$ such that $bz=1_G.$ This $z$ is denoted as $b^{-1}.$... (2b). Any $b\in H$ has a unique inverse $b'\in H,$ that is, a unique $b'\in H$ such that  $bb'=1_H.$ By (1b) we have $1_G=1_H$, so $bb'=1_G,$ so by  (2a) we have $b^{-1}=b'\in H$.

(3). If $a,b\in H$ then $a,b^{-1}\in H$ by (2b), and the product of members of $H$ is in $H$, so $ab^{-1}\in H.$

Addendum. An example of a structure $G$ that is $not$ a group, and a sub-structure $H$ where none of this works. Let $G$ be the set of all functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R.$ For $f,g\in G$, define the function $fg\in G$ by $(fg)(r)=f(r)g(r)$ for each $r\in\Bbb R.$ The function $1_G,$ where $1_G(r)=1$ for every $r\in \Bbb R,$ is the only $f\in G$ such that $fg=g$ for $all$ $g\in G$... Let $H=\{f\in G: f(0)=0\}.$ Then $H$ has an identity too: $1_H(r)=1$ if $0\ne r\in \Bbb R,$ and $1_H(0)=0.$

Comment: Exercise: Prove the converse. That is, if $H$ is a non-empty subset of a group $G$ and if $\forall a,b\in H\,(ab^{-1}\in H)$ then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.